# How to pass a pinged username and a variable to a bot command

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to make a ranking system bot and I need to be able to pass in the command another user and an int variable like

```
[Command(/*@user*/ + " Has won round " + /*int*/)]
```

Is it even possible? *(keep in mind I am pretty much a noobie so a simpler solution is generally better for my needs)*

Edit: I forgot to add the discord.net part also in the title which has caused some misunderstandings but now it is fixed. also a little bit of fixing to the wording

Comment: You might need to be more specific about which is your problem and what have you tried so far. I'm guessing it's related to "discord.net" just due to the question's tag.

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate multiple strings into one? Like `$"{user} has won the game with a score of {score}"`?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you provided is completely invalid. The `Command` attribute is used to define the command name, not accept parameters for the command. Expected command input (command parameters) are set in the command method's signature.

```cs
// example command call: !sample @RandomUser 25
[Command("sample")] 
public async Task ExampleCommand(IUser user, int num)
{
    // Do stuff
    await ReplyAsync($"{user.Mention} has won round {25}");
}
```